# "Exchanged with" vs. "exchanged for"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Is "exchanged with" grammatically correct and does it mean the same thing as "exchanged for?" "For" and "with" don't normally seem interchangeable, so these two phrases should be different, yet they seem similar.

Answer (score 8):

*Exchange with a person* you are transacting with

> I exchanged wares with the baker today.

*Exchange a thing you spent for a thing you received* as in a purchase or scheme

> I exchanged a sack of flour for a rhubarb pie.

*Exchange one thing with another* if you control both of them (less frequent)

> It wouldn't all fit in my bag, until I rearranged the things in my bag by exchanging the pie with the dictionary.

Comment: I think you're on to something there, but I'm not sure exactly what. It seems **for** is more normal where *both* items being exchanged are mentioned, whereas **with** can be used where only one (or indeed, neither) are explicitly named in the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

It may be that for *some* speakers, and/or in *some* contexts, the two expressions are interchangeable, but I don't think that applies to *most* usages.

**Exchanged with** is relatively uncommon. It's used when sub-elements of a system under consideration are being altered for some reason (optimisation, analysis, etc.) And in the sense of *exchanged correspondence/contracts/currency/etc. with*.

**Exchanged for**, the more common form, generally implies a transaction (barter, swap, whatever) between two parties. Normally in contexts where one or both 'exchangers' consider the exchange to be at the very least 'fair', if not actually 'advantageous'. These are *not* relevant issues in the contexts outlined above where *with* is normally used.

[image]
LATER: It's been pointed out that there are specific contexts where the two usages would be considered different by almost all speakers, even if they wouldn't conciously acknowledge or adhere to the distinction given above.

[Here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=exchanged%20for%20him,exchanged%20with%20him&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is an NGram specifically graphing written usage of **exchanged for him** compared to **exchanged with him**. If you leaf through some of them, you'll see that the vast majority of references to **with** are *in the specific contexts* specified above, even though these contexts represent a tiny proportion of all references to 'exchanging' in general.

Comment: That's an awesome graph - how did you get it?

Comment: @krubo Google Ngrams

Comment: Any references for those usage definitions?  They sound very plausible, but some backup would be nice.  I might also be worth mentioning that "exchange with _someone_" and "exchange for _someone_" have entirely different meanings.

Comment: @Rhodri: as @Ham and Bacon noted, it's an NGram graph. I just spent a couple of minutes leafing through a few pages of the reported instances in their indexed books to confirm what I already suspected. Of all things that may be *exchanged*, 'people' aren't particularly common. So I didn't consider that special difference, because OP only seems to be asking about standard usage for standard situations. Perhaps I should add that subtle distinction anyway - I just didn't want to confuse the issue first time around.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if you could cite sources on the _definitions_ you give for "exchanged with" and "exchanged for", that would be very useful for the future.  I should probably have also been clearer that in both "exchange with _someone_" and "exchange for _someone_", the person is participating in the exchange, not being exchanged.  These are common usages, and may be messing up your Ngrams.

Comment: @Rhodri: I think this is rather too subtle a point to expect we should find dictionary definitions making the distinction. I personally produced 'definitions' which may or may not be the end of the story, but the *reason* for making those distinctions is a combination of 'gut feel' and cursory analysis of other people's written usage. And as pointed out, exchanges involving *named people* (either as 'agents' or barter objects) are a small proportion of all references. So they won't significantly affect the graph, even though they're relevant to the more precise distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this column is very helpful, but here, respondents are not answering the key problem - i.e., which is the "new" (the replacement), and which the "old") (the replaced), in usage such as "XYZ was exchanged **for** ABC". It is just assumed that the reader understands (I assume XYZ to be the new).
In academic Konglish (Korean English), the phrase "XYZ is exchanged **to** ABC" is quite often used, and I still have not been able to figure out which way around it applies, i.e., which is the new and which the old. But which is which is the key issue, to avoid ambiguity - which can be critical in scientific papers. (In Konglish, there are other similar uses of "to" that make the native reader pause, and wonder which order applies).

Answer (score -1):

"Exchanged with" and "exchanged for" are interchangeable.

There is only one instance, in which "exchanged with" must be used, and that is referring to the time when you are exchanging with somebody i.e.

> I exchanged with John/I exchanged for John.

Usually, "exchanged with" can be interchangeable with "exchanged for", but in this case, you can see that this is not possible. It's only these instances that "exchanged with" is needed.

Comment: As I'm sure you realise, I agree with you that in general, semantically and grammatically both forms are interchangeable, and neither is meaningfully more 'correct' than the other. As for 'special exceptions' such as the example you give, I'm inclined to agree. But I'm not *yet* sure exactly why, or what the defining characteristics of the exceptions are. It would be nice to chase this one down a bit more.

Comment: I don’t agree that they are genetically interchangeable, even with the caveat. “I exchanged a book for a pen” doesn’t retain its meaning when you change *for* to *with*.